# Serverside save standalone SWF with parameters

Tags: flash, flv

I have this system where a client uploads a logo of a company and I resize it and place it in a SWF file for preview (using some FlashVars variables) in order to make a preview of how the animation is going to look like.

Is there a way to save this preview as a standalone SWF file and then as a FLV file?

For the second question (the conversion one) is there any other possibility than ffmpeg?

Thank you!

**Update:**

Actually I would like to know how theese guys http://www.flashbannernow.com save their flash banners since they do not have any GET or Flashvars variables in the embed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research a friend of mine gave me a brilliant example of this http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Screen_or_Stage_Capture_with_Flash-18504.html which actually is a **component for AS 3** that **makes a screen capture** and then **saves it as a FLV** which actually is a great job that does not require any licence or so whatsoever.

Here would be the class that creates the FLV file http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/

After this by the way someone could easily use ffmpeg for compression or other file formats.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to 'save this preview as a standalone SWF' is to modify your current swf to be intentionally dynamic, taking in a variable that represents the image.

so on your server you would have: 
-- www.yourserver.com/some_dir/app_dir/your.swf?image_id=abc.jpg
-- www.yourserver.com/some_dir/app_dir/uploaded_images_dir/

currently your client sends images to you, you manipulate them, then you upload them to your server, uploaded_images_dir.

Then when your swf is called it will read GET value and use it to load the image from uploaded_images_dir into your_mc.

Your client merely has to type in your url with the image name appended.

Comment: I agree with you but this is what I want to avoid, respectively the GET variables are only used for preview and FlashVars does this job very well, but after that I will need to convert this SWF in a FLV or another video format that does not support at all any GET variables.